# How to make request to internal API with Express in node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have an API that I have previously defined like this.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  //API implementation
});
```

I now have a second part of the API that needs to use the login API for verification.

```
app.get('/changePassword', function(req, res){

  //Make request to /login endpoint and verify user credentials

});
```

How do I make a request to the login API from the change password function?

Comment: you can either make request to `localhost` using `request` npm module or any similar npm modules OR you can use `res.redirect`.

Comment: Thanks! To anyone having the same problem, I had tried using request but it didn't respond with anything, it turns out I had just forgotten the `http://` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function

```
res.redirect("/login");
```